# How to load LDAP configs in Spring Application lazily.

Tags: java, xml, spring, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I have application-context.xml which is having beans like below.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" >
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/DB_NAME" />

</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" name="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and one context.xml like

```
<ResourceLink name="DB_NAME1" global="application/cn=MyDB,ou=Database Connections" />
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

If you notice in my context.xml I kept my resource name as **DB_NAME1**

I also kept **default-lazy-init="true"** in **beans** tag at the top of my application-context.xml file. Still I am getting below error

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [DB_NAME] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [DB_NAME].
```

So my question is, How to load my jdbcTemplate/dataSource lazily.

Because in my application some of the services are hitting DB and some are hitting other services. So in case even if DB is down the other services should not stop working.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the temporary solution of my problem.

Wrote new method which is searching for JNDI config and creating jdbcTemplate and if it fails to do so, I am eating the exception.

```
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    try {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        myDataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/DBNAME");
        myjdbcTemplate = new org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

This method I am calling every time from my other DAOImpl methods like below

```
  getJdbcTemplate().query("MySp", args, myBeanRowMapper);
```

Its working for now. But if you see any better approach, please answer here.

Thanks